# Unreal Engine Packaging Error: Unknown Error

Tags: packaging, unreal-engine5

I tried to package my project in unreal engine 5 but I got an unknown error.
What should I do? I tried changing the image but it still did not work.

I tried changing the image but it still did not work.
I don't know what to do as I tried fixing the error.